# Hola, estoy muy perdido al hacer una consulta y poner sus respectivas comillas, utilzando Netbeans con MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

```
String sql = " SELECT e.idempleado FROM empleados e  
    WHERE idempleado IN 
        ("SELECT et.idempleado FROM empleado_turno et WHERE et.idturno IN ("SELECT dt.idturno FROM dia_turno dt WHERE dt.iddia = '"
    +("SELECT iddias FROM dias WHERE nombre='"
    +diaSeleccionado+"'" AND '" 
    + idempleado=e.idempleado+'";
```

Esa es la consulta, si alguien me puede ayudar a colocar sus comillas respectivas se los agradezco. Gracias!!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si la ordenas un poco y le haces caso a la ide, se arregla sola.... si los colores parecen raros, ahi es donde deberias mirar... no hay que poner comillas porque si...

Answer (score 0):

```
 String sql = " SELECT e.idempleado "
                +" FROM empleados e  "
                +" WHERE idempleado IN (SELECT et.idempleado "
                                    + " FROM empleado_turno et "
                                    + " WHERE et.idturno IN (SELECT dt.idturno "
                                                         + " FROM dia_turno dt "
                                                         + " WHERE dt.iddia =  (SELECT iddias "
                                                                           + "  FROM dias "
                                                                           + "  WHERE nombre='"+diaSeleccionado+"'"
                                                                           + "  AND  idempleado=e.idempleado+)"
                                                         + ")"
                                    + ");";
```

Comment: Se lo agradezco un monton!!! Muchisimas gracias Omar

Comment: Me lanzo el siguiente error                                 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')))' at line 1

Comment: Ya, en el ultimo ) ponle ; ya edite

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente! Pero me sigue lanzando el mismo error. Quizas falte alguna comilla simple. pero gracias en serio

Comment: Creo que el error estaba en el primer parentesis del final  AND  idempleado=e.idempleado+)", era AND  idempleado=e.idempleado+")"